# django filtering after aggregation

Tags: django, filter, aggregation

lets say I have a aggregation to show total number of orders of each sales rep created:

```
orders.values('sales_rep__username', 'sales_rep__email').annotate(Count('sales_rep'))
```

then how do I go about only select the sales reps have more than 100 orders created? Given the order table has too many records to iterate through code.

Note: I can only think about writing my own custom SQL statement, a colleague of mine came up a hack to use extra() method to inject a custom where subquery, but which isn't optimized for sql execution plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the annotated value and use it in filter.

```
orders.values('sales_rep__username', 'sales_rep__email').annotate(order_count=Count('sales_rep')).filter(order_count__gt=100)
```